# Can a Windows 7 computer contain foreign characters for a login password

Tags: windows-7, security

Trying to harden our servers and would like to know if its possible for a windows 7 box to contain foreign characters for a login password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it depends on the characters in question, not sure how passwords would work with [IME](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Input_method_editor) for example, but I myself have swedish characters (å, ä, ö) in my password without issues.